# MySQL how to select a table from horizontal to vertical

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I am currently having this table named as student:

| name | fieldColumn | fieldvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | math | A |
| A001 | english | B |
| A002 | math | C |
| A002 | english | A |

And I want to select as a new table like this as 'math' would be named as class1, and 'english' would be named as class2

| name | class1 | class2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | A | C |
| A002 | B | A |

Can someone help a query to do that? I was trying to join but got no luck. Thank you.

**I found the same question here [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql) which is counting. But my question is just showing fieldcolumn and fieldvalue.**

Comment: It’s called a pivot